# Calling a sp in loop

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services, cursor, temp-tables

I am using this to call a sp multiple times

```
     declare @field1 date
     declare cur CURSOR LOCAL for
     select  b.thedate from [GENESIS_SCO].[dbo].ExplodeDates('20140415','20140417') b
     open cur
     fetch next from cur into @field1
     while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
     exec GENESIS_SCO..Get_TTIRA3 N'2101', @field1,1,9901023
     fetch next from cur into @field1
     END
     close cur
     deallocate cur
```

This is returning me a dataset for n times, where n is the number of times that the loop has been run for. With these parameters it is returning 50,60 and 120 rows for different values of field1.

I need all the 230 rows (50+60+120) rows in a single dataset so that i can make reports with it in SSRS.

Suppose in first iteration its returning

```
    VALUE | CODE
   --------------
    BLUE  | 234
    PINK  | 755
    LILAC | 734
```

IN SECOND ITERATION

```
    VALUE   | CODE
   --------------
    RED     | 245
    SILVER  | 755
    BLACK   | 76555
```

IN THIRD ITERATION

```
    VALUE        | CODE
   -------------------
    BROWN        | 9282
    QUICKSILVER  | 2542
    YELLOW       | 55
```

What i need is

```
     VALUE       | CODE
   --------------------
    BLUE         | 234
    PINK         | 755
    LILAC        | 734
    RED          | 245
    SILVER       | 755
    BLACK        | 76555
    BROWN        | 9282
    QUICKSILVER  | 2542
    YELLOW       | 55
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use table variable(above SQL Server 2000) or temp table to accumulate the produced recordsets in it.

```
 declare @field1 date
 declare @tmp table(value varchar(20), code int)
 declare cur CURSOR LOCAL for
 select  b.thedate from [GENESIS_SCO].[dbo].ExplodeDates('20140415','20140417') b
 open cur
 fetch next from cur into @field1
 while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
 insert @tmp exec GENESIS_SCO..Get_TTIRA3 N'2101', @field1,1,9901023
 fetch next from cur into @field1
 END
 close cur
 deallocate cur
 select * from @tmp
```

Comment: Its throwing an error saying that : An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested. Do we have any other option?